# Why Isn't The /playsound Command Working In 1.7.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently playing Minecraft 1.7.2 and am using a command block in a roller-coaster.  I am trying to make a command block play the sound "moan1" from the "resources" folder in the directory "newsound"  I am using the command as so: `/playsound moan1 @p`

I did make sure I had all the different sounds on and I know there is a redstone signal going to it.  I have checked Google for information but all the pages are outdated for 1.6 or their sounds are stored differently.

What have I done wrong with this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the /playsound command, I add a mob. bit. It goes kind of like this when I type in playsound: 'playsound mob.ghast.scream' (that's when I want a ghast scream).
You cannot use a specific noise, as I have tried that, and it does not work, for example 'mob.ghast.scream1'. You have to take away the number. Unfortunately, that means that you will not be able to have a specific zombie moan, so then there will be a random moan of a zombie every time you activate the command block. This is how I would type in a perfect playsound command: 'playsound mob.zombie.moan @p (or username)'.
I also check that the command block's redstone is wired up correctly by typing in the command '/say @a hello'. If the redstone works correctly, it would say to everyone on the server (or just you if it's on single player) 'hello'. This ensures that the command block works when the redstone turns on. If you're still stuck, I'm terribly, terribly sorry but I will no longer be able to help you, as this is most of my knowledge put into a forum post.

Answer (score 5):

If the sound `moan1` is in the `newsound` folder you have to play it like
 `/playsound newsound.moan1 @p`

Comment: It still doesn't work do I need to add newsound.ghast.moan1 because the sound is located in the ghast folder?

Comment: Most likely, @EthanBaconGaming, that is what you need. It's telling the command where exactly to look. The `ghast` folder inside the `newsound` folder.